# Implementing the PRNG xoshiro256+ in Swift for a RN in a given range?

Tags: swift, algorithm, math, random

Based on the source written in c: [here](http://xoshiro.di.unimi.it/xoshiro256plus.c).

I'm trying to implement the xoshiro256+ pseudo random number generator (PRNG) in Swift. I need to get to a point where the algorithm gives me a number between 0 and 1 that I can then multiply by a given range's count and then shift by the first number in that range.

So far I've rewritten what's listed in the source here:

```
func rotl(_ x: UInt64, _ k: Int) -> UInt64 {
    return (x << k) | (x >> (64 - k))
} // This is the rotating function.

var s: [UInt64] = [1,2,3,4] // I gave a seed vector of the basic 1234.

func next() -> UInt64 {
    let result_plus = s[0] + s[3]

    let t = s[1] << 17

    s[2] ^= s[0]
    s[3] ^= s[1]
    s[1] ^= s[2]
    s[0] ^= s[3]

    s[2] ^= t

    s[3] = rotl(s[3], 45)

    return result_plus

} // This returns the next number in the algorithm while XORing the seed vectors for use in the next call.
```

But after calling the "next" function 6 times I get an error which I'm guessing is for exceeding UInt64's max limit. **This is only a guess.**

How would I proceed to achieve what I'm after from this point? I'm guessing I need to discard the lower bits to be able to continue calling the "next" function without exceeding UInt64 and from there I would need to convert to a double somehow? **I'm actually lost at this point.**

Comment: Just in case anyone comes along to use this, in my tests this can be significantly sped up by replacing the array with 4 ivars (s0, s1, s2, s3). Mutating an array involves bounds checking, and can prevent some other optimizations that explicit ivars can avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR cannot overflow, so your problem is with the addition.  Change `let result_plus = s[0] + s[3]` to `let result_plus = s[0] &+ s[3]` (note the '&') to tell Swift you want the addition to truncate on overflow.  You can read the section on 'Overflow Operators' in Apple's book "The Swift Programming Language" for more details.

To convert to `Double` use:

```
Double(next() >> 12) / 0x10000000000000
```

A `Double` has 52 mantissa bits, and the hex value is 2**52. This uses the upper 52 bits of your `UInt64` to yield a result in the range [0,1.0) with the highest achievable precision.

Comment: Thank you for this! Apparently C automatically overflows and I was unaware; so this is actually intended in the algorithm. Do you know how I could convert to a number between 0 and 1? I was thinking cast to `Double` then divide by `Double(UInt64.max)`?